# How can I resolve this GXTest in Genexus?

Tags: genexus

I was trying to install GXTest into my Genexus 15 by adding all the files the oficial tutorial told me to add. I also run the install command in the command line. When I finished, I realized that I already had it installed. 
Right now I have two test buttons in the menu and the UI tests I want to create do not work. 
[image]

Whenever I try to create a new one I get this error:
[image]

I would really appreciate your help because I am new to Genexus and I am really lost with this error.

Answer (score 2):

Have you resolved this?

What GXtest versions are you using? I recommend you that install only one version (the proper one for your GeneXus version).

Download links are here: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?42858,GXtest+4+Releases+-+Public+Channels,#Preview+Channel

The error it's because you have 2 versions installed.

To view your GXtest versions installed go to Tools -> Extensions Manager. Once you are there uncheck one of GXtest4 and it's correspondant GXtest4BL and apply changes.